# Capybara's page.has_text? always returns true

Tags: capybara

I am using Capybara with Minitest and I am encountering some really weird behavior. In previous tests everything went as expected but in a new test class `page.has_text?(any_text)` returns true with any string as `any_text`. Literally any string, which makes `has_text?` very unreliable. Could there be any logical explanation for this?

I also printed out the body of the page through `page.html` and the text is really not present.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean that `has_text?` is always returning true or that the test is always passing?

Comment: That has_text? is always returning true.

Comment: Are you sure that `any_text` is set correctly? I think this behaviour would only occur when `any_text` is `nil`.

Comment: No, I actually did not use a variable. I just did it for illustration. I used a regular string in `has_text?`. Also tried both double and single quotes.

Comment: In the meantime, did you try `page.has_content?(any_text)?`

Comment: Yeah, I did. It had the same result. Finally upgrading the capybara version fixed it, so it was probably a bug.